# what is difference on iterating differently in python dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, iteration, time-complexity

I have a dictionary like below

```
G = {0: {1: 1, 4: 1}, 1: {0: 1, 2: 1}, 2: {1: 1, 3: 1}, 3: {2: 1, 4: 1}, 4: {0: 1, 3: 1}}
```

I can iterate over they keys in two ways:

```
for key in G:
    do stuff
```

and also like

```
for key in G.keys():
    do stuff
```

Which one is better & pythonic way ?
 Also which one is better in time-complexity ?

Comment: Exercise: you can check whether a key is in a dictionary either by `key in some_dict` or by `key in some_dict.keys()`. 1) Are they equivalent in asymptotic complexity? 2) Compare the answer for (1) in python2 and python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of both approximately are same O(N) but in second you have to pay a bit time for extract `keys` !

For better understanding look at the run time of both :

```
def test1():    
   G = {0: {1: 1, 4: 1}, 1: {0: 1, 2: 1}, 2: {1: 1, 3: 1}, 3: {2: 1, 4: 1}, 4: {0: 1, 3: 1}}
   for key in G:
    key+=1

def test2():    
   G = {0: {1: 1, 4: 1}, 1: {0: 1, 2: 1}, 2: {1: 1, 3: 1}, 3: {2: 1, 4: 1}, 4: {0: 1, 3: 1}}
   for key in G.keys():
    key+=1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print 'test 1 : ',timeit.timeit("test1()", setup="from __main__ import test1")
    print 'test 2 : ',timeit.timeit("test2()", setup="from __main__ import test2")
```

result :

```
test 1 :  0.934647083282
test 2 :  1.02073597908
```

Comment: The startup and teardown time Python itself takes is way too high to show the difference properly. Use the `timeit` module to show performance differences instead.

Comment: yep , surely , using `time` command is my habit ! i will edit the answer !

Answer (score 2):

`for key in G` is the most efficient  way,  both methods are `O(N)` but  `for key in G`   avoids building a list unnecessarily as you do using `G.keys()` and an extra function call.

```
In [3]: G = {0: {1: 1, 4: 1}, 1: {0: 1, 2: 1}, 2: {1: 1, 3: 1}, 3: {2: 1, 4: 1}, 4: {0: 1, 3: 1}}

In [4]: %%timeit 
   ...: for k in G:
   ...:    pass
   ...: 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 171 ns per loop

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: for k in G.keys():
   ...:     pass
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 235 ns per loop
```

Comment: That only applies to Python 2.x - in Python 3.x, `keys()` returns an iterator.

Comment: @isedev the question is tagged 2.7 and in python 3 you are still using an unnecessary function call

Comment: @isedev: and that's still *an extra method call*, and the creation of a new object (a dict view).

Comment: However, it is *not* O(1). It is still O(N), but the fixed cost is lower.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yep, read the question wrong was thinking if `if k in d`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: You can talk about the `iter()` call that the `for` statement makes. `iter(G)` is O(1), `iter(G.keys())` is O(N). But add the `for` loop and both are `O(N)`, as it'll add the loop. O(1) + O(N) and O(N) + O(N) both make O(N) asymptotically speaking, but I'd pick the one with the lower fixed cost any day.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks yes, I understand, I was just thinking of `in d`  being `O(1)`, think I need a coffee

Answer (score 0):

The most common would be `for key in G:` with all the aforementioned benefits.

The `for key in G.keys():` is useful if you manipulate the dictionary in the loop, which is prohibited with the more efficient first variant. With manipulation of the dictionary i mean explicitly changing dictionary-keys (adding/deleting items)! Doing so would lead to a `"RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"`. But you may change the associated values of a key also in the first variant, because it doesn't change the dictionary(-length), but rather the associated values of a key.

So there's no real "better", just two use-cases! Regularly you would use the first variant, but in case you want to iterate over the dictionary AND also manipulate it, you would use the second.

**edit**:
As pointed out by Bakuriu in python3 you would have to manually convert `G.keys()` to a list. My example was meant for the tagged version 2.7.

Comment: you can't modify a collection while iterating over it! what would be the next item? with dict.keys() you iterate over a list of the keys and may add or delete elements of the dictionary.

Comment: Warning: iterating over `keys()` and modifying the dictionary works only in python2. In python3 `keys()` is a view and hence you must manually convert it to a `list` to make that work.  @PadraicCunningham Try something like: `for i, key in enumerate(some_dict): if i % 2 == 0: del some_dict[key]`. By "modifying" here we mean that the dictionary changes its size either by adding or removing elements. Re-mapping the same key isn't a problem.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: You will get a "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" if you add or delete keys.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: What do you want? Maybe i wasn't explicit enough, but the ONLY thing you are allowed to change are the values. You may NOT change (the values of) the keys, because that would mean adding a new item, which would change the size! I explicitly pointed that out now to avoid perceived ambiguity.